# rails3 view has_many :through attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, pluralize

Three models linked via has_many :through

```
class Bozza < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accessoryvolumes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :accessories, through: :accessoryvolumes
  belongs_to :lavorazione

class Accessory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accessoryvolumes
  has_many :bozzas, through: :accessoryvolumes

class Accessoryvolume < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accessory
  belongs_to :bozza
```

In the view for bozza, the attributes for bozza are accessible

```
<% @bozza.accessoryvolumes.each do |accessoryvolume| %>
  <%= accessoryvolume.numero %> 
  <%= accessoryvolume.bozza_id %> 
  <%= accessoryvolume.bozza.lavorazione.name %>
  <%= accessoryvolume.accessory_id %> 
  <%= accessoryvolume.accessory.name %>
```

save for the last item.  Any attribute for the relationship to accessory generates and

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

evan though accessory_id has a value.  How is the related attribute in one instance being picked up and not the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the plural handling of "accessory". *it was a nasty suspicion for many hours...*.

This issue arises rather frequently.  Pony up and come up with a name that cannot be interpreted mistakenly by rails or someone, somehow, somewhere.  Avoid nouns that pluralize irregularly. Moreso when dealing with foreign languages.

Now

```
class Accessorio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lavoraziones
  has_many :accessoryvolumes
  has_many :bozzas, through: :accessoryvolumes
```

and

```
<%= accessoryvolume.accessorio.nome %>
```

runs as expected

Comment: You can look into configuring the Rails Inflector and over-ride how it handles certain names that end in "y"

Comment: That's useful, thanks!  Naming is so fundamental - I've noted these odd cases where Rails sort of forgets;   I'm not certain I could catch the appropriate Inflector behaviour...